# pinch and expand UIView

Tags: iphone

I'm planning to create a UIView with UIButtons and I want that UIView to add in a UIViewScroll. But my problem is that UIView is larger than the actual screen size of the phone, so I want a pinch or expand gesture to zoom in or zoom out the view. My question is how can I implement the resizing of the view including its sub views like the UIButtons? Should I recreate all the objects inside of the view with new dimensions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the autoresizingMask property of the UIView. you can set this mask to all subviews of your main view. then they will change their frames automatically.